# Apostrophe Not Being Inserted into SQL Database

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, pdo

I'm using PHP to connect with a SQL database using `sqlsrv` drivers. However, I've run into a problem:

```
$string = "Home";
$DBH->prepare( "INSERT INTO table_name (column_name) VALUES ('" .$string. "')" );
$DBH->execute();
```

How come this works?

```
$string = "Home's";
$DBH->prepare( "INSERT INTO table_name (column_name) VALUES ('" .$string. "')" );
$DBH->execute();
```

But this doesn't?

The SQL database doesn't seem to accept the apostrophe in the `$string` variable. In the past I would use `mysql_real_escape_string` but that isn't an option.

Comment: Does and doesn't work are words noone understands here. Find the error. PDO has a quote method http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.quote.php

Comment: You're suffering SQL injection - Here's [how to fix it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: "In the past I would use `mysql_real_escape_string` but that isn't an option." This means you know what the problem is. Use prepared statements.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario — More then that, that's is the *cause* of the problem, so the question you link to is a duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because you're using a prepared statement... but not preparing any input and instead just slapping the value into the SQL. Looking at it should make it clear:

ex 1:

```
$DBH->prepare( "INSERT INTO table_name (column_name) VALUES ('Home')" );
```

ex 2:

```
$DBH->prepare( "INSERT INTO table_name (column_name) VALUES ('Home's')" );
```

See how your quoting is now messed up?

The proper way to do this is to acutally USE the prepared statement's functionality:

```
$string = "Home's";
$DBH->prepare( "INSERT INTO table_name (column_name) VALUES (:column_name)" );
$DBH->bindParam(':column_name', $string);
$DBH->execute();
```

Note how your statement is FIRST prepared with the `:column_name` parameter ready to accept a value. Then the `bindParam` puts a value in and executes.

Now can even reuse the prepare with new values:

```
$string = "Home's Holmes is homing";
$DBH->execute();
```

Comment: I'd forgotten about OOP with PHP, thanks for the refresher lesson

Answer (score 0):

The [`sqlsrv` documentation page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-query.php) has decent examples on how to use prepared statements:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO table_name (column_name) VALUES (?)";
$params = array("Home's");    
$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql, $params);
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to escape the apostrophe by using a double apostrophe. after you do an insert check out the data in the table it should only show one apostrophe.

```
$string = "Home''s"; 
$DBH->prepare( "INSERT INTO table_name (column_name) VALUES ('" .$string. "')" );
$DBH->execute();
```

good luck...

Comment: This is not a string-escaping problem, it is a SQL statement problem.

Comment: in SQL apostrophes' need to be escaped..                       Insert into Person
(First, Last)
Values
('Joe', 'O''Brien')

Comment: That's kind of acceptable for static queries, but I'm pretty sure that `$string = "Home's";` is just a simplified test case. The SQLSRV libraries offers decent prepared statements support.

Comment: Agreed. It is still advisable to use prepared statements.

Comment: I don't disagree however I feel the OP couldn't grasp that concept..